# I have a python file IO program that will not return a the Issuer ID name based a substring entered by the user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, file-io, credit-card

I cannot get my for loop to iterate a text file and return a delimited result based on a substring entered by user. I keep getting the whole issuer ID network instead of just the specific ID network.

How can I optimize this to return the correct result?
Please Enter Your Card Number: 5558397375275489
Luhn Verification: Authentic
Credit Card Issuer: AmericanExpress
Credit Card Issuer: ChinaT-Union
Credit Card Issuer: ChinaUnionPay
Credit Card Issuer: Dankort
Credit Card Issuer: DinersClub-CarteBlanche
Credit Card Issuer: DinersClub-International
Credit Card Issuer: DinersClub-USA&Canada
Credit Card Issuer: Discover
Credit Card Issuer: InstaPayment
Credit Card Issuer: JapanCreditBureau(JCB)
Credit Card Issuer: Maestro
Credit Card Issuer: MasterCard
Credit Card Issuer: RuPay
Credit Card Issuer: UATP
Credit Card Issuer: Verve
Credit Card Issuer: Visa
Credit Card Issuer: VisaElectron

Is the current output.
5558397375275489
Is an example of an input by user
Planned output would be
Please enter a credit card number:
5558397375275489
Credit card number: 5558397375275489
Credit card type:   MasterCard
Luhn verification:  Authentic.

This is the txt file attached:

```
ChinaUnionPay;16,19;62,88
Dankort;16;5019
DinersClub-CarteBlanche;14;300,301,302,303,304,305
DinersClub-International;14;36,38,39
DinersClub-USA&Canada;16;54
Discover;16,19;6011,622126-622925,644,645,646,647,648,649,65
InstaPayment;16;637,638,639
JapanCreditBureau(JCB);16;19,3528-3589
Maestro;16,19;5018,5020,5038,5893,6304,6759,6761,6762,6763
MasterCard;16;51,52,53,54,55,222100-272099
RuPay;16;60,6521,6522
UATP;15;1
Verve;16;506099-506198,650002-650027
Visa;13,16,19;4
VisaElectron;16;4026,417500,4405,4508,4844,4913,4917
```

```
       #!/usr/bin/env python3
       import csv
       import utils

       def user_choice(card_verify, card_number):
           result_one = utils.is_valid(card_verify)
           if result_one == False:
            print("Luhn Verification: N/A")

           else:
               result = utils.luhn(card_number)
               state = "Authentic" if result else "Unauthentic"
               print('Luhn Verification: ' +  state)


        def file_iterator(card_issuer, card_verify, length):
            cards = []
            with open('credit_card_types.ssv', 'r') as card_file:
                for lines in card_file.readlines():
                    issuer_id, card_len, id_num = lines.strip().split(';')
                    cards.append({'Issuer' : issuer_id, 'Length' : card_len, 'Id_num' : id_num})
                    id_number = id_num.replace(',' , ' ')
                    card_length = card_len.replace(',' , ' ')
    
                    for issuer_id in card_verify:
                        if card_issuer in id_number:
                            print("Credit Card Issuer: " + issuer_id)
                                break
              

        def main():
            card_number = list(input("Please Enter Your Card Number: ").strip())
            card_verify = ''.join(card_number)
            length = len(card_verify)
            print(length)
            card_issuer = str(''.join(card_verify[0:6]))
            user_choice(card_verify, card_number)
            file_iterator(card_issuer, card_verify, length)

        if __name__ == '__main__':
           main()
```

Comment: Please include an example of input, the expected output, and the output you get instead?

Comment: an example of an the input would be 5558397375275489 Credit card number: 5558397375275489
Credit card type: MasterCard
Luhn verification: Authentic. (Would be the expected output.